# foreach 2d array assignment

Tags: java

The following code assigns roughly half the values in a 2d array of bools to true, the other half to false:

```
boolean[][] btab = new boolean[10][10];
for (int row = 0; row < btab.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < btab[row].length; col++) {
        btab[row][col] = (Math.random() < 0.5);
    }
}
```

I thought the following code using foreach loops would do the same thing...

```
boolean[][] btab = new boolean[10][10];
for (boolean[] row : btab) {
    for (boolean b : row) {
        b = (Math.random() < 0.5);
    }
}
```

But all the values in the 2d array are false, which I guess means that either the assignment just isn't happening or b is a copy of the value of the boolean I want to assign to, not a reference to it. Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. For reference, the relevant bit of the Java spec is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

Answer (score 4):

Your guessing is correct, in case of primitives (like boolean type), the variable in the enhanced for is just a copy of the real value in the array.

When it comes to objects, then you get a copy of the reference value (not the real object), so you can modify its contents, but not replace the object i.e. create a new instance and replace the actual object. Example:

```
List<SomeClass> lstSomeClass;
//create and fill the list...
for(SomeClass sc : lstSomeClass) {
    //this will modify the current sc object data
    sc.setSomeAttribute(someNewValue);
    //this will compile but it won't replace the currenct sc object in the list
    sc = new SomeClass();
}
```

If you want to make the code work, use the first way to fill the array.

Answer (score 3):

Foreach loop returns the value of the element of the array, not a reference to it. Foreach cannot be used to modify the values in an array of primitives. Even in an array of objects, you can modify the contents of objects, but not references that are stored in the array.